# Naming of the parts of the fundamental theorem of caclulus

Tags: calculus, terminology

Mathematicians have corrected me in the past for saying "the 1st FToC" and told me that I was actually referring to "the 2nd FToC," and vice versa.

From my observations it seems that there is no consensus for naming the two parts of the fundamental theorem of calculus.  A quick example of this can be seen between [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) and [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html).  To be specific, they have interchanged parts 1 and 2.

Why does this happen?  Is there no convention for which part is which?

Comment: Maybe we should take a cue from lawyers naming parts of the Constitution. We might call one "the open interval clause" and the other "the closed interval clause."

Comment: I studied the convention followed by Wikipedia. Anyway the distinction between the two parts occurs only when the function being integrated is discontinuous. Perhaps to stay correct one can just write FTC instead of FFTC and SFTC.